# TSQL add or delete rows inside procedure based on selection

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have table that holds user access rights:

```
  Id  |  UserId  |  SectionId
  ---------------------------
  1   |  1       |  1
  2   |  1       |  2
  3   |  2       |  1
  4   |  1       |  3
```

Using this code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@List    NVARCHAR(2000), 
                       @SplitOn NVARCHAR(5)) 
returns @RtnValue TABLE ( 
   id    INT IDENTITY(1, 1), 
   value NVARCHAR(100)) 
AS 
BEGIN 
  WHILE ( Charindex(@SplitOn, @List) > 0 ) 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue 
                    (value) 
        SELECT Value = Ltrim(Rtrim(Substring(@List, 1, Charindex(@SplitOn, 
                                                       @List) 
                                                       - 1))) 

        SET @List = Substring(@List, Charindex(@SplitOn, @List) + Len( 
                                     @SplitOn 
                                     ), 
                    Len 
                    (@List)) 
    END 

  INSERT INTO @RtnValue 
              (value) 
  SELECT Value = Ltrim(Rtrim(@List)) 

  RETURN 
END
```

I created a function that returns (for now all records for specific user and sections):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateSettings(@UserId int, @NewSettings nvarchar(255))
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * 
  FROM settings
  WHERE 
    UserId = @UserId AND 
    SectionId IN (SELECT convert(int,Value) FROM dbo.Split(@NewSettings,','))
END;
```

This is available to test at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79de7/4

I would like to modify this procedure so it will remove items that exists and will add new that don't.

Here is an example. I want to change this:

```
  Id  |  UserId  |  SectionId
  ---------------------------
  1   |  1       |  1
  2   |  1       |  2
  3   |  2       |  1
  4   |  1       |  3
```

Into:

```
  Id  |  UserId  |  SectionId
  ---------------------------
  1   |  1       |  1
  3   |  2       |  1
  4   |  1       |  3
  5   |  1       |  4
```

This should be done by calling:

```
EXEC UpdateSettings @UserId=1, @NewSettings='2,4'
```

Because there is row for UserId=1 and SectionId=2 procedure should delete it and because for userId=1 and SectionId=4 row don't exists I would like to create it.

My first idea was to create a cursor for NewSettings and then check if that row exists, if yes delete it, if no add it.

Second idea was to remove all already existing rows like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateSettings(@UserId int, @NewSettings nvarchar(255))
AS
BEGIN
  DELETE 
  FROM settings
  WHERE 
    UserId = @UserId AND 
    SectionId IN (SELECT convert(int,Value) FROM dbo.Split(@NewSettings,','))
  END;
```

This way I'll be able to remove already existing records, but no ideas how to add new ones (like in my example I must remove one row as it exists in table and add one new)

I would like to avoid cursor and maybe do some kind of JOIN, but I have no ideas how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this I would keep it simple:

1. delete all existing data for the user
2. insert all new data for the user

The benefits are:

- Easy to code
- Easy to understand
- The optimization you are hoping to achieve is probably so tiny it isn't worth the trouble

Comment: Yes I understand that this would be the easiest way. My procedure is called from asp page. I have a really big table with checkboxes and to minimize the request I'm only sending changes to server. If I have 1000 checkboxes (just an example) and user only change one and click save button I only want to update that setting-delete that row or add new record. I this that this is better than deleting 1000 rows and adding 1000 new.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server2005

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateSettings(@UserId int, @NewSettings nvarchar(255))
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @tmp TABLE(UserId int, SectionId int)
  DELETE s
  OUTPUT DELETED.UserId, DELETED.SectionId INTO @tmp
  FROM settings s JOIN (
                        SELECT @UserId AS UserId, CONVERT(int, Value) AS SectionId 
                        FROM dbo.Split(@NewSettings, ',')  
                        ) d ON s.UserId = d.UserId AND s.SectionId = d.SectionId 
  INSERT settings(UserId, SectionId)
  SELECT @UserId AS UserId, CONVERT(int,Value) AS SectionId
  FROM dbo.Split(@NewSettings, ',') d LEFT JOIN @tmp t ON CONVERT(int, d.Value) = t.SectionId 
                                      LEFT JOIN settings s ON @UserId = s.UserId AND CONVERT(int, d.Value) = s.SectionId
  WHERE t.UserId IS NULL AND s.UserId IS NULL
END
```

In SQLServer 2008

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateSettings(@UserId int, @NewSettings nvarchar(255))
AS
BEGIN
  MERGE settings AS target
  USING (
         SELECT id, @UserID AS UserId, value AS SectionId 
         FROM dbo.Split(@NewSettings,',')
         ) AS source
  ON (target.UserId = source.UserId AND target.SectionId = source.SectionID)
  WHEN MATCHED
    THEN DELETE
  WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (
                 UserId,
                 SectionId
                 )
         VALUES (
                 source.UserId,
                 source.SectionId
                 );  
END
```

Comment: 2008 looks so better, it's a shame I can't use it... Thanks for Your replay, I'll check it right away :)

Comment: I agree with you and power of MERGE;)